# Trying to installing python modules in Ubuntu, I cannot find them in the official repo

Tags: drivers, python3

In the PyPi repo there were several modules I was using. (Gekko, Control, and Inspyred). I cannot find their equivalent in the Ubuntu official package repo. Have they been renamed or were they not built for Lunar. This has been an issue since the change to install python modules using apt (apt install python3-numpy)

https://pypi.org/project/gekko/
https://pypi.org/project/control/
https://pypi.org/project/inspyred/

Comment: You can use pip to install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in the official Ubuntu 23.04 repositories for Gekko, Control, and Inspyred Python packages.